# Basic program hanging at nextInt()

Tags: java

I have just started my 2nd programming course at college and our first assignment is rather simple, intended to basically check our environment and to check we know how to submit assignments through the course website.

When I run the code we have been supplied with, it hangs where it is supposed to prompt for the user to enter a number, so that it can print it. I inserted a series of println statements to determine where it was hanging.

It prints TEST1, TEST2 and TEST3, but never makes it to TEST4. So there must be something wrong with the line:
number = input.nextInt();

But I can't for the life of me see what's wrong with that line. Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Anyway, here is the code

```
package rossassignment1;
import java.util.Scanner;  // use the Scanner class located in the "java.util" directory

public class RossAssignment1 {    
   public static void main (String[] args) {
     System.out.println("TEST 1"); 
     int number;
     System.out.println("TEST 2"); 
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("TEST 3"); 
     number = input.nextInt();
     System.out.println("TEST 4"); // display the number with other messages
     System.out.print("This program reads an integer from a keyboard,\n"
               + " and print it out on the display screen.\n"
               + "The number is: " + number + ".\n"
               + "make sure that you get the exact same output as the expected one!\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: So, is the website supposed to enter anything at the prompt?

Comment: nextInt() is waiting for a human to type an integer in the command line and press enter, are you doing it?

Comment: I just realized that the problem was me. The program was waiting for me to enter a number!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the line input.nextInt() is run the program is waiting for the user (you, or whatever marking system is being used) to input an integer in the console. After you do so the program will continue to your TEST4 line.

Answer (score 0):

If after entering an integer, the codes after that still don't show up, you can do this:

```
number = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();  //Add this
```

It will clear the newline.

Alternatively, I prefer to do this:

```
number = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
```